# Where can I find the source code for calculating the Game Rotation Vector and Rotation Vector in Android git?

Tags: android, android-source

I am currently struggling to reproduce the game rotation vector and rotation vector values (quaternion) from acceleration, gyroscope, and magnetometer. All of them are acquired from the Android Sensor API.

However I am not getting any good results, so I decided to look into Android git, hoping to find some source codes for the calculation process.

I did bump into this [SensorManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f868ed/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java) code, but I cannot find the procedure for the calculation of the game rotation vector in this file. Searching with Google using site:android.googlesource.com option did not give me any satisfying results yet.

Can anybody give me the right file to look into for the android implementation of Game rotation vector and Rotation vector?